# Android : Difference between View.GONE and View.INVISIBLE?

Tags: android, android-xml, xml-attribute

What is the difference between `View.INVISIBLE` and `View.GONE` for the View visibility status?

Comment: When a View is gone, it means it doesn't take any space in the layout. When it is invisible, it will take the necessary room in a layout but you just don't see it.

Answer (score 834, accepted):

INVISIBLE:

> This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

GONE:

> This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

Comment: Looks like analogous to `display:none` & `visibility:hidden` in HTML/CSS :-)

Comment: Or to Hidden and Collapsed in Wpf XAML

Comment: If it is invisible, will click on it is also disabled?

Comment: @KuldeepYadav yes it will be in both gone and invisible.

Comment: just for future curious readers: we can still use performItemClick  on list/grid views even it is invisible.

Comment: when i use `gone` the touch doesn't work at that place.

Comment: Note that INVISIBLE still makes the view clickable; it is the same as VISIBLE but without being shown.

Answer (score 317):

From [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) you can say that

> ***View.GONE*** This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for
> layout purposes.
>
> ***View.INVISIBLE*** This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

---

***Lets clear the idea with some pictures.***

*Assume that you have three buttons, like below*

[image]

*Now if you set visibility of Button Two as invisible (`View.INVISIBLE`), then the output will be*

[image]

*And when you set visibility of Button Two as gone (`View.GONE`) then the output will be*

[image]

Hope this will clear your doubts.

Comment: what if i use it for edittext. is it possible to get the value from edittext ?

Answer (score 35):

For ListView or GridView there is an another difference, when visibility initially set to

INVISIBLE:

> Adapter's getView() function called

GONE:

> Adapter's getView() function didn't call, thus preventing views to load, when it is unnecessary

Answer (score 10):

INVISIBLE:
The view has to be drawn and it takes time.

GONE:
The view doesn't have to be drawn.

Comment: View is not drawn, it is measured and laid out.

Comment: @cyroxis maybe he/she means ondraw method!

Answer (score 10):

I'd like to add to the right and successful answers, that if you initialize a view with visibility as `View.GONE`, the view could have been not initialized and you will get some random errors.

For example if you initialize a layout as `View.GONE` and then you try to start an animation, from my experience I've got my animation working randomly times. Sometimes yes, sometimes no.

So before handling (resizing, move, whatever) a view, you have to init it as `View.VISIBLE` or `View.INVISIBLE` to render it (draw it) in the screen, and then handle it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, It working only sometimes when view is `GONE`

Answer (score 4):

when you make it Gone every time of compilation of the program the component gets initialized which means you are removing the component from the layout and when you make it invisible the component it will take the same space in the layout but every time you don't need to initialize it.

if you set Visibility=Gone then you have to initialize the component..like

eg

```
Button _mButton = new Button(this);
_mButton = (Button)findViewByid(R.id.mButton);
```

so it will take more time as compared to Visibility = invisible.

Answer (score 4):

- **View.INVISIBLE**->The View is invisible but it will occupy  some space in layout
- **View.GONE**->The View is not visible and it will not occupy any space in layout

Answer (score 1):

`View.GONE` - The view will not show and the rest of the views will not take its existence into consideration.

`View.INVISIBLE` - The view will not show, but it will take its assigned space in the layout.