# Remove white Space after hide views in scrollview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have **UIScrollview** with dynamic views(Label, Imageview) inside it. I hide some views but white blank space is there. how can I remove it?

I tried with below code but it doesn't work,

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
```

The layout of File Like:

```
-View

 -ScrollView

  -UIImageView

  -UIButton

  -UIButton

  -UILable

  -UILable

  -UIButton

  -UILable

  -UILable
```

Comment: can you provide any screenshot ?

Comment: use this [layoutsubviews](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews), and change your constraints in this method. If doesnot help then try same in [layoutIfNeeded](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded). It will helps you.

Comment: Do use a view under Scrollview and all your other object in that view.

Comment: @AbhishekMitra Please look at question i have added. all views are inside scrollview

Comment: What about using `UITableView` to achieve what you want? By doing so, you can "hide" views by using a datasource tied to the tableView, and then change the datasource, allowing the tableView to show only what is in the datasource.  Afterall, `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` and gives you a lot of behavior for free to achieve what you want.

Comment: Do Use
 -View

 -ScrollView

  - UIView

     -UIImageView

Answer (score 1):

Just hiding views won't help, as it still will take place. You have several options:
1. Each of views inside scrollView should have height constraint that should be set to 0 when hiding is required. Then you should call

```
[scrollView setNeedsLayout];
[scrollView layoutIfNeeded];
```

2. You can remove unneeded views from scrollView by calling

`[viewToHide removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. if i use [viewToHide removeFromSuperview];

will it remove space @CrazyJoeLv