# Android: move views downward to make space for form field errors

Tags: android

Below is an Android screen that I am developing.

[image: An AnDroid screen]

If user input data is not correct when the next button is pressed, I would like to move the views below the button downward so that I can display error messages. (For example, "name cannot be blank")

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside button click event

```
editTextName.setError("name cannot be blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to use `yourEditText.setError("error..")`, but be aware there is a [bug in this for 4.2](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40417)

If you want to be specific with the design, you can add a `TextView` below your `EditText` and make sure that your `TextView` [visibility is set to View.GONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556607/android-difference-between-invisible-and-gone). When you run your validation method, you just need to set the view to `View.VISIBLE` if there is an error, respectively. Android will handle reflowing the layout.