# Showing/Hiding ImageView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Relative Layout that has two children, an ImageView and a ProgressBar. While the image for the ImageView is loading I want to show the spinning progress bar, and once the image has finished I want to hide the progress bar and show the Image. I can never get the image to show up, but the progress bar shows just fine. I have verified that the image is being loaded, this seems like a layout issue but is beyond me...

**this is my layout file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:visibility="visible"/>
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**When Loading image...**

```
final RelativeLayout relLayout = (RelativeLayout)convertView;
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)relLayout.getChildAt(0);
final ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar)relLayout.getChildAt(1);

bar.setIndeterminate(true);
bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**And inside the onSuccess of my imageLoader**

```
bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
imageView.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
relLayout.requestLayout(); // also tried invalidate(), and nothing at all
```

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

`imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

with

`imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Also check [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556607/android-difference-between-invisible-and-gone)

Comment: this was actually the right answer... I was surprised. I was under the impression that setting it to INVISIBLE would still reserve layout space, which is why I went the GONE. As soon as I switched to INVISIBLE, I was able to hide/show a spinner or image easily

Comment: I have faced that problem once. I did that and problem solved. I do not understand why this solution downvoted. Weird people...

Answer (score 0):

First in your XML put this line in your ImageView **android:visibility="gone"**

Then into your code use an asynkTask to show the progressBarr and when the download finish hide the proogressBar and show the ImageView

```
public void getImage(){
   new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>(){
      @Override
      protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params){
         //Code to load image, take care don't change the UI because it can break the app
      }
      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values){
         //Here you can update your progressBar
      }
      @Override
      public void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
         //When the image finish the load here you can hide the progressBar and show the ImageView
        bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
   }.execute();
}
```

I hope have helped

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to keep id for the views because when the item is being gone, then the position of the view will get changed
please try like this

Your Layout:
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_view"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:visibility="visible"/>
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

In your java class:

ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findviewbyId(R.id.img_view);
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)findviewById(R.id.progress_bar);
imgView.setVisiblity(View.INVISIBLE);
progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
In your oncomplete listener
imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
progressBar.setVisibility(VIEW.INVISBLE);
```