# Android: How do I put a solid color rectangle in a Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a RelativeLayout that inflates just fine.  I would like to add a solid color rectangle spanning the width of the layout at the top.  I tried putting the following into my xml:

```
<view android:id="@+id/top_alert"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/orders_gridview"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/table_request_assistance"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

Now, when I try to inflate my Layout I get a NullPointerException at LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (line 715):

```
if (name.equals(TAG_1995)) {
```

`name` is set earlier thusly:

```
if (name.equals("view")) {
    name = attrs.getAttributeValue(null, "class");
}
```

Evidently there is no "class" attribute.  How do I add that?  I can't find anything close in http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android. Should I add it?  Is this the standard way to do this?  It seems like it should be the simplest thing in the world.

Comment: Can you also post the exception

Comment: What happens when you replace `<view` with `<View`?

Comment: You can use a TextView with no text. I upvoted as I'd like to know the standard answer to this.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Well, now it inflates.  Ok so "view" is nothing and "View" is a View?  I wonder what that code is supposed to do.  What is the expected situation where name would equal "view"?  Post this as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @pbabcdefp I have a hunch this is the standard way to do this.  I just had a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes are case sensitive - in this case, you are using the [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) class and therefore it needs to be exactly `View` in your XML.

Answer (score 11):

For the noobs here is some more general markup.  This will print a 10-pixel high grey rectangle spanning the top of its parent view at the top.

```
<View android:id="@+id/rectangle_at_the_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#DDDDDD"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

## Explanation:

**This is the rectangle's id:**

```
android:id="@+id/rectangle_at_the_top"
```

This says **make the View as wide as the parent:**

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Note you'll sometimes see `"fill_parent"`.  That has been deprecated in favor of `"match_parent"`.

This says **make the height 10 "ensity-independent pixels high:**

```
android:layout_height="10dp"
```

What is a "density-independent pixel" you ask?  I'm not 100% sure, but these guys know:  [What's the difference between px, dp, dip, and sp in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

This says **align the rectangle with the top of the parent View:**

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

More accurately it makes the top edge of the View the same as the top edge of the parent.  Want to put something at the bottom?  Yup, you guessed it:  use `layout_alignParentTop`.

This says **set the background color to a grey-ish color:**

```
android:background="#DDDDDD"
```

DDDDDD is a color value.  You can find examples of other color values and how Google suggests to use them here:  [Google's Android Color Guide](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html)

Finally, this says to **make this View visible:**

```
android:visibility="visible"
```

This is mostly redundant as they are visible by default.  Other options include "invisible" and "gone" which sound similar but are crucially different.  For more info see this discussion:  [What is the difference between "invisible" and "gone?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556607/android-difference-between-invisible-and-gone)