# hide view on drawingcache bitmap

Tags: java, android, android-layout, drawingcache

I've a layout and elements. I want to get the drawingcache from the toot element but one text view should not be visible on the bitmap.

Are there any ways to do that?
I tried to make the element invisible, but that doesn't work the way I did.

Comment: have you tried visibility="GONE" instead of "INVISIBLE"?

Comment: not yet - what does it do and can i make it visible again?

Comment: Sure you can make it visible again from GONE to VISIBLE. Read more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556607/android-difference-between-invisible-and-gone

Comment: yes it works! thx || but actually the position of the view shouldn't be the problem because its floating