# Visibility of Button

Tags: java, android, xml, button

How do I make a button invisible and when I need it I set the text of the button. Heres the code I tried,This is the MainActivity.class.

```
 getSupportActionBar().hide();

  phno=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
```

}

```
public void get(View view){
    String ph=phno.getText().toString();
   Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
   btn.setText("Call"+ph);
   btn.setTextSize(30);
}
```

Here's the xml folder:

```
EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginTop="119dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:hint="Enter Phone Number"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ok"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText3"
    android:onClick="get"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText3"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
```

When I enter the number and click Ok, nothing happens. Please help,

Answer (score 1):

```
btn.setVisibility(VIEW.GONE);  //hide
btn.setVisibility(VIEW.INVISIBLE);//transparent
```

refer to this for the difference:
[Android : difference between invisible and gone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556607/android-difference-between-invisible-and-gone)

Answer (score 0):

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

To hide the button

```
View.GONE
```

To transparent view of the button use

```
View.INVISIBLE
```

Comment: There's a typo: `b.setVisibility(View.GONE);` should be `btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);`