# AdMob does not refresh the ad after hiding/showing AdView

Tags: android, admob

I would like to add AdMob ads to my application, but I have a problem with showing/hiding them depending on the internet connection status of the device. When I turn on my device with WiFi turned on the ad is shown correctly, when I turn the WiFi off, the ad is hiding also corectly. But when I go from "no internet" state to WiFi/3G on the ad is not showing. Instead I get suchmessages in Logcat:

```
04-15 13:16:03.688    8813-8813/com.package.app I/Ads﹕ Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
04-15 13:16:03.688    8813-8813/com.package.app I/Ads﹕ Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
```

Activity's code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /***/   

        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                super.onAdLoaded();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
@Override
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.resume();
        }
    }

@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.pause();
        }
    }

@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.destroy();
        }
    }
```

I would like to turn the ads on and make the `AdView` visible when the user turns the internet connection on, and hide it when the user loses the internet connection. What's wrong with my approach? Is it possibile to do this without internet connectivity state listener?

Comment: Try to again load Ad when visible like : AdView.loadAd(new AdRequest()); or try to set refreshInterval  attribute.

Comment: Use `View.INVISIBLE` instead of `View.GONE`. Also read [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556607/android-difference-between-invisible-and-gone)

Comment: @BatuhanCoşkun `View.INVISIBLE` is not what I am looking for since I want the banner to be gone from my layout when internet connection is off

Comment: @HareshChhelana But how can I detect the moment when the user turns on the Internet connection?

Comment: But after using `View.GONE`, it is removed from your layout and you can not bring back it without refreshing the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect when the user changes his connection, you should register a `BroadcastReceiver`, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888502/how-to-detect-when-wifi-connection-has-been-established-in-android).
And for hiding/showing `AdView`, I am using one `RelativeLayout`as holder, and I am hiding it instead of `AdView`.

Comment: Why are you wrapping `AdView` inside `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: It is a routine of mine. That is just a suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

If anybody still has problem with that, this code will check every REFRESH_RATE_IN_SECONDS if can get new ad when internet is off. Code is taken from [here.](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.si/2012/06/show-custom-image-when-no-admob-ad-is_21.html)

```
private int REFRESH_RATE_IN_SECONDS = 5;
AdView adView;
private final Handler refreshHandler = new Handler();
private final Runnable refreshRunnable = new RefreshRunnable();
AdRequest adRequest;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)     
            .build();

    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode){
            refreshHandler.removeCallbacks(refreshRunnable);
            refreshHandler.postDelayed(refreshRunnable, REFRESH_RATE_IN_SECONDS * 1000);
        }
    });

    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

}

private class RefreshRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Also, constructor `Handler()` is now deprecated, refer to this answer on how to use `Handler` now. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/63851895/4315001].

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem but i do a simple hack..hope this will help but i don't think this is good approach because adview is continuously requesting ads.

```
 public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
    super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

  }
```