# Android force LinearLayout to resize views after view removal

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I 've a LinearLayout with 2 views, view A which takes some vertical space, and view B which takes the rest of the layout.

```
<LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/ly2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/input"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" >
        </View>

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

At some point I want to remove view A. How do I tell LinearLayout to refresh so view B takes the entire space?

Best Regards.

Comment: use `setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
View v=(View)findViewById(R.id.view1);
```

at some point use

```
v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556607/android-difference-between-invisible-and-gone) for more help

Comment: I see. This works, but why just removing the view from the Layout does not change the layout ?

Comment: try   `linearLayout.invalidate();` after removing `view`

Answer (score 2):

try to replace your xml with this code

```
<RelativeLayout

        android:id="@+id/ly2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" >
        </View>

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

In your main activity where this xml is used put this

```
View view=(View)findViewById(R.id.view1);
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```