# Can I set my button as optional showing depend on how many data I fetch?

Tags: android, button

I had fetch xmlData to my app sucessfully, and I need to transform these data as button for user to select.

The question is...
If my app just get 10 of data, I only want to show up 10 buttons in my scrollView.
I had try to set button as invisible, but there will show those invisible button as a "blank button"...

Please give me a help, thanks guys.

Comment: just try this code `Button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` otherwise paste your code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set the Visibility of the button to "gone" and it will hide the button

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE).
```

Here is a nice stackoverflow post about the difference between View.GONE and View.INVISIBLE:
[Android : difference between invisible and gone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556607/android-difference-between-invisible-and-gone)

**BUT**

In your case if you want to dynamically display buttons you should use a ListView or a RecyclerView.

Here is a nice tutorial about how to create a RecyclerView.

http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-recyclerview-tutorial/

Comment: @himaChen It is not the right way to to use visibility to dynamically display buttons

Comment: In the first part of the answer I showed the right way to hide a view.              In the second part I mentioned the best solution in this particular situation. So I don't get your comment and the downvote too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically add the button for these kinds of operation.

Example

```
<ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/buttons_layout/>

</ScrollView>
```

inflate the buttons programatically

```
Linearlayout buttonsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewByID(R.id.buttons_layout)

buttonsLayout.removeAllViews();

for(int i= 0; // based on how mych data you have
{
  Button button = new Button(context);
  button.setOnClickListener() //

  buttonsLayout.addView(button);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom listview instead of scrollview with a button as a row of listview and set adapter of listview when your data is receive from server.