# Invisible still holds that place

Tags: android

I have two textviews and one button. The first textview is to get user email address, once user clicks on the send button, it sends him a pin number. initially pin number textview is invisible, if pin number is sent to email address and then it becomes visible.

My question why there is space a between the first textview and the button, because of initially pin textview invisible. I though that it automatically aligns when the pin textview becomes visible. Why it still holds its place. I wonder how could I solve that issue?

```
editTextEmail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
editTextPin = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextPin);                                      
editTextPinLayout =(TextInputLayout) view.findViewById((R.id.editTextPinInputLayout));
editTextPinLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
buttonSend = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
```

Comment: How about making it View.GONE that would hide it altogether and remove the space . Once you have the response do View.VISIBLE

Comment: How could I able to bring it then? I am testing it now.

Comment: Ya i edited the comment,

Comment: That's because `INVISIBLE` occupies the `Widget's` space as against `GONE` that doesn't. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11556629/450534. As already suggested by @Dhina, use `editTextPinLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`View.GONE` that would hide it altogether and remove the space. 
 Once you have the response do `View.VISIBLE`

Comment: it is right answer, I am going to mark it once stack overflow allows me.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `View.GONE` instead of `View.INVISIBLE`

**setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)**

> This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

**setVisibility(View.GONE)**

> This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

Finally

```
editTextPinLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```