# I would like to Gone the button

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In xamarin Android we have `"Visibility.Gone;"` to hide the button. In Xamarin Forms we have `IsVisible="{Binding State}"`, but this only will make view invisible, space remain there.

Please let me know solution.
Regards

Comment: best solution is to use c# code rather than xaml I believe. xamarin forms is still missing a collapsed option like wpf has

Comment: This is not true! I've tried this, if you are using Grid and assigning row and column to the button, then only it is possible to, that is the grid cell which will keep the space.

Comment: Share your xaml. It looks like you have something wrong

Comment: <Grid Column="5">
<Grid.Padding>
 <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0,-3,-20,-3" Android="0, -5, 0, -5" WinPhone="20, 20, 20, 20" />
 </Grid.Padding>
  <Label Text="{Binding Description}" IsVisible="{Binding State}" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="White"  Font="Bold"  FontSize="9" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />    </Grid>

Answer (score 0):

In your view model you need to have something similar to the following:

```
public bool State{
    get {
        return _state;
    }
    set {
        _state= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged ("State");
    }
}
```

According to the Xamarin documentation found [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.IsVisible/) the element should be removed from the visual tree and not take up any space.

**Edit:**

 I'm not sure how you're setting the Column="5" on your grid. There is no attribute for Grid that contains column; however, I am able to produce the effect you looking for with the following code.

```
 <Grid BackgroundColor="Gray">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.Padding>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0,-3,-20,-3" Android="0, -5, 0, -5" WinPhone="20, 20, 20, 20" />
        </Grid.Padding>
        <BoxView Color="Blue" Grid.Column="0"></BoxView>
        <BoxView Color="Green" Grid.Column="1" IsVisible="{Binding State}"></BoxView>
        <BoxView Color="Blue" Grid.Column="2"></BoxView>
        <BoxView Color="Green" Grid.Column="3"></BoxView>
    </Grid>
```

**Details:**

You are correct in that setting the label visibility to false in a grid will maintain the space allocated to the control in the grid. What you can do is set the grid `<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />` or `<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />` and put your label into that column or row. This will automatically remove the space allocated for the control when the visibility is set to false. Below is a screenshot of the effect you are getting (left) and the effect after setting the **Definition** to **Auto** (right).
[image]

Comment: yes i have, but my question is i want to make my button "Gone" no "Invisible", there is big difference between  "Gone" and "Invisible"

Please check below link for difference
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556607/android-difference-between-invisible-and-gone

Comment: Yep you're correct. I misunderstood the problem. What type of layout contains the element you are trying to "Gone?" I've solved this issue a number of ways, but I'll need to know which layout you are using in order to supply you with a more direct solution.

Comment: I am using this, I want to Gone label.
 
<Grid Column="5"> <Grid.Padding> <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0,-3,-20,-3" Android="0, -5, 0, -5" WinPhone="20, 20, 20, 20" /> </Grid.Padding> <Label Text="{Binding Description}" IsVisible="{Binding State}" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="White" Font="Bold" FontSize="9" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" /> </Grid>