# Changing visibility of Android ProgressBar

Tags: android, visibility, android-progressbar

I've a condition check to decide if the `ProgressBar` should appear or not. The layout looks like below where the `ProgressBar` is contained within a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/someID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/someProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the fragment :

```
 ProgressBar progressBar;

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup   container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_main_layout, container, false);
 progressBar =(ProgressBar) root.findViewById(R.id.someProgressBar);
 ....
```

}

and I programtically try to change the visibility of the progress bar with the  `setVisibility()` function like:

```
   if(someCondition)
       progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   else
       progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

But the above never works. So I tried to make changes at the `xml` level by adding `android:visibility="gone"` which sets the initial visibility to `GONE` state, but I'm again lost on how to make the ProgressBar visibile.

I appreciate your thoughts on this.

Thanks.

Comment: It means you must check your condition. Does it satisfy?

Comment: @Piyush : I've just given the basic structure of the code. I know for sure the condition works (through debugging).

Comment: @vardhinisuresh27 just check if you are setting visibility of correct progress bar ,  you initialized your progressbar as `someProgressBar`  and you are setting visibility to `progressBar`  . Also try changing your progressbar as global variable and see.

Comment: @Redman Thanks. I've edited the post. I just have one progress bar and it is declared as a global variable in my code.

Comment: @vardhinisuresh27 your problem is solve or not??

Answer (score 4):

you can try to this hope this can help you.

```
ProgressBar someProgressBar;
TextView txtSend;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtSend = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSend);
    someProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.someProgressBar);
    someProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    txtSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (someProgressBar.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                someProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                someProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with below,

```
if(someCondition)
   progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 else
   progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: you havn't changed much, it wont make any difference.Invisible will just Occupy space even after going. take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556607/android-difference-between-invisible-and-gone)

Comment: Ya I have same issue, some time relative layout creates this issue.
Ya but it will occupy space in the layout.

Comment: @KeyurThumar This doesn't help.

Comment: @vardhinisuresh27 Please add your full layout code.
or try to change parent layout to linear layout. Just do for try.

Comment: @KeyurThumar Changing the parent from `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` did not help.

Comment: @vardhinisuresh27 add your full code of layout.xml file

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using wrong id for progress bar.

```
ProgressBar someProgressBar=(ProgressBar) root.findViewById(R.id.someProgressBar);

   if(someCondition)
       someProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   else
       someProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and change your xml code for progress bar.If you want by defaultprogress bar to hide,then keep it as it is,otherwise remove visibility from xml.