# two buttons are not appearing in my layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Hi i am trying to figure out the error but still i couldn't :(. Following is the link to get my activity layout xml.(i am sorry SO didn't allow me to write it here because of character limit  :( )

[link to code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4obmllo494itm6p/code.txt?dl=0)

The problem is when i set visibility of "main" layout to visible and all others to invisible (which is what i want to do)  the buttons "bilateral" and "guassianblur" not appearing just black space for those buttons appears. other buttons appearing good. i tried changing the size parameters but still no luck. can anybody guide me through this?  following is the way i set visibility

```
mainview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
lightview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
colorview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
dilateview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
erodeview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
blurview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
medianview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
guassianfiltering.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
bilateralfiltering.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: why down vote :( ?

Comment: instead of `INVISIBLE` do `GONE` and check

Comment: just replace INVISIBLE to GONE

Comment: Maybe, "bilateral" and "guassianblur" are not appearing because you set their visibility to View.INVISIBLE?

Comment: Thanks to all for your kind replies. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `android:visibility="gone"`instead of "invisible".
See [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556607/android-difference-between-invisible-and-gone)

Answer (score 1):

**instead of Invisible use visibility GONE**

```
mainview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
lightview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
colorview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
dilateview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
erodeview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
blurview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
medianview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
guassianfiltering.setVisibility(View.GONE);
bilateralfiltering.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: if it works..then please accept the answer so others can use this code.

Answer (score 0):

`View.VISIBLE` means that view should be visible to user and user can interact.

`View.INVISIBLE` means that view should not but visible to user so that they can't interact with view but view occupies the same space as in visible state.

And, `View.GONE` means that view should not be available to user as well as doesn't occupy any space in the screen, also doesn't affect other view.

[Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)