# android studio issue: complex Layout is not showing in design view but just as XML

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have a somewhat complex `layout.xml` file (353 xml lines, 16kb) with multiple nested constraint layouts. This particular xml file is only showing a blank white screen in the design tab but works well when I run it on device and emulator. I have other smaller layout files which show the design normally on android studio but it seems that there is a bug with viewing larger xml files.

Is this a known issue? I tried refreshing layout and removing android studio cache but nothing seems to work. any ideas?

I do not think it has anything to do with the code since it runs normally on device and I am not sure posting the whole xml file on SO is a good idea.

## update

What I realised is that all the elements in the layout seem to be 'invisible' at the top left corner since when I hover over them the pointer turns into a hand and when I click , certain elements get highlighted in the component tree. This is a screenshot of what I am seeing:

[image]

Comment: Make a github snippet or something and link it here for us to look at. Also take a screenshot of the design preview so that we can see it.

Answer (score 0):

I added `android:visibility="gone"` which is vital to my app. Little did I know that it also applies to the design view which I find to be really useless. I want the visibility to be gone during runtime, not on a platform where I am supposed to be tweaking the design of the UI. This is ridiculous to me.

Does anyone know If I can keep visibility="gone" but still see the design in the design view of the layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tools:visibility="visible"` for designing purposes.
It has zero effect on the view in real use.

**Don't forget** to keep your `android:visibility="gone"`.

In general, use [tools attributes](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes) whenever you'd like to manipulate a preview in the designer while keeping your view attributes valid for real use.

**Edit:**

Keep in mind that there is a huge difference between `invisible` and `gone`. [More about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556607/android-difference-between-invisible-and-gone)