# Responsive layout position in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

I just want to change the position of my Image and button if I select `no` in my spinner,the  asset should automatically goes up if selects `no`, the thing is it remains steady since I used `android:layout_below="@+id/sample"` and my Idea is when selecting `no` the `layout_below="@+id/` will change pragmatically, is this possible?. If not do you have any idea aside from changing layout programitacally?

```
if yes = Unhide asset

else if no = Hide asset then change layout below through an ID
```

[image]

**XML**

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewScanned"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@color/background"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:text="Scanned details"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewScanned"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_fieldset_background"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tViewId"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:text="Cash card"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ScannedImage"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/tViewId"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_outline"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_image" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgUri"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/tViewId"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_outline"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_image" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/rescanCashCard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tViewId"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:text="SCAN"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_cashCard"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imgUri"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                app:helperText="Good valid!"
                app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_creditcard">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/Idresult"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Cash Card no."
                    android:inputType="number" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_series_number"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/til_cashCard"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                app:helperText="Good valid!"
                app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series_no">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt_series_no"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Card series"
                    android:inputType="text" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_isID"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/til_series_number"
                app:helperText="Required"
                app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_credit_card_off_24">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerIsID"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:hint="ID exists"
                    android:inputType="text" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tViewAdditionalId"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/til_isID"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:text="Additional ID"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgAdditionalId"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/tViewAdditionalId"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_outline"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_image" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_scanID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/til_isID"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/tViewAdditionalId"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:text="SCAN"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tViewCashCard1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/imgAdditionalId"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:text="Grantee"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/PsID1"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/imgAdditionalId"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_outline"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_image" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/rescanBeneId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/btn_scanID"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/tViewAdditionalId"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:text="SCAN"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />


        </RelativeLayout>
```

**java**

```
 spinIsID.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
                    if (spinIsID.getText().toString().matches("Yes")) {
                        btn_scanID.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        tvAdditional.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        imgAdditionalId.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    } else {
                        btn_scanID.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        tvAdditional.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        imgAdditionalId.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
btn_scanID.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
tvAdditional.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                        
imgAdditionalId.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

with

```
btn_scanID.setVisibility(View.GONE);
tvAdditional.setVisibility(View.GONE);                        
imgAdditionalId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

[Difference between invisible and gone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23211042/11805824)