# Android Circular Determinate ProgressBar

Tags: android, material-design, android-progressbar, material-components-android, progress-indicator

I want to create a Circluar Determinate ProgressBar, the kind which shows the Progress in the center of the Bar. Is there any default way to create this, or will i have to create my own custom one.

Comment: Most likely a duplicate of this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259506/i-want-progress-circle-instead-of-progress-dialog

Comment: @AlexBottoni no, thats about indeterminate progress bar. Very different

Answer (score 46, accepted):

First add a progress_circle.xml to your res/drawable directory like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:drawable="@drawable/progress_circular_background"/>
<item>
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3.4"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="6.0" >
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#ffffffff"
            android:startColor="#ffffff"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="true" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <rotate
        android:drawable="@drawable/progress_particle"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="360" />
</item>

</layer-list>
```

I Googled image searched both "progress_particle.png" and "progress_circular_background.png" (with quotes) since the android default drawables for those were missing.  You'll probably want to customize those but they'll do to get you started.

Then in your xml layout:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/timer_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="60"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_circle" />
```

My max is 60, since I'm using it for a seconds timer, but you might have something different.

The trick is that you need to use style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" even though it's a circular progress.

Comment: what type of drawable is the progress_circle.xml?  The one you provided is not a complete file, it needs an upper level object to be part of

Comment: Fixed. Copy paste didn't show the enclosing tags for some reason, but they were there!

Comment: Could ring shape (not progress particle) start filling from -90 degrees (hour 12)?

Comment: I have one small question. There are drawable-ldpi,drawable-hdpi,etc. Which folder should I use for this xml?

Comment: @bagusflyer put it into folder named "drawable", xml files are dpi independent resources.

Comment: `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"` is not necessary, `android:indeterminateOnly="false"` is.

Comment: Drawables can be dowloaded here: https://github.com/michelou/android-examples/tree/master/android-sdk/ApiDemos/res/drawable-hdpi

Answer (score 65):

I have written detailed example on [Android circular progress bar](https://demonuts.com/circular-progress-bar/) here on my blog [demonuts.com](http://demonuts.com) You can also fond full source code and explanation there.

Here's how I made circular progressbar with percentage inside circle in pure code without any library.

[image]

first create a drawable file called `circular.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="6"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="20.0"
            android:useLevel="true">


            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#999999"
                android:endColor="#999999"
                android:startColor="#999999"
                android:type="sweep" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="270"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="270">

            <shape
                android:innerRadiusRatio="6"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thicknessRatio="20.0"
                android:useLevel="true">


                <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="0"
                    android:pivotX="50%"
                    android:pivotY="50%"
                    android:toDegrees="360" />

                <gradient
                    android:centerColor="#00FF00"
                    android:endColor="#00FF00"
                    android:startColor="#00FF00"
                    android:type="sweep" />

            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now in your `activity_main.xml`  add following:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dialog"
    tools:context="com.example.parsaniahardik.progressanimation.MainActivity">

    <ProgressBar

        android:id="@+id/circularProgressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular"
        android:secondaryProgress="100"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@drawable/whitecircle"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="25%"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In `activity_main.xml` I have used one circular image with white background to show white background around percentage. Here is the image:

[image]

You can change color of this image to set custom color around percentage text.

Now finally add following code to `MainActivity.java` :

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int pStatus = 0;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Resources res = getResources();
        Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.circular);
        final ProgressBar mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.circularProgressbar);
        mProgress.setProgress(0);   // Main Progress
        mProgress.setSecondaryProgress(100); // Secondary Progress
        mProgress.setMax(100); // Maximum Progress
        mProgress.setProgressDrawable(drawable);

      /*  ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mProgress, "progress", 0, 100);
        animation.setDuration(50000);
        animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        animation.start();*/

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while (pStatus < 100) {
                    pStatus += 1;

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            mProgress.setProgress(pStatus);
                            tv.setText(pStatus + "%");

                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        // Sleep for 200 milliseconds.
                        // Just to display the progress slowly
                        Thread.sleep(8); //thread will take approx 1.5 seconds to finish
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

If you want to make horizontal progressbar, follow this link, it has many valuable examples with source code:
http://www.skholingua.com/android-basic/user-interface/form-widgets/progressbar

Comment: why is it so much of extra spacing outside progressbar? How do I reduce it

Comment: changed `android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"` from `6` to `2.5`

Comment: changed the from `android:innerRadiusRatio="6"`  to `android:innerRadiusRatio="2.35"` it's perfect with almost no extra space

Comment: top, great solution!

Answer (score 9):

For the *determinate* part of your question, [material design library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases) now supports determinate circular progress bars:

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

For more info refer [here](https://material.io/components/progress-indicators/android#using-progress-indicators).

Other answers may help on how to insert the progress label in the center.

Comment: Anybody knows how to implement it... The documentation doesn't help. Just can't get it to work....

Comment: @whoadityanawandar I've not used these myself but if by implementing you mean make the progress bar determinate in code, the documentation suggests this:
`int progress = getLoadingProgress()

indicator.setProgressCompat(progress, true)`

Comment: Thanks, although this still looks incomplete, I mean how do you set the timer for it and all...

Comment: Thank buddy :D I am asking myself why we need to custom a very common element like progress bar

Answer (score 9):

An example of a determinate circular progress indicator

```xml
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:progress="75"
  app:indicatorColor="#FF0000"
  app:indicatorSize="100dp"
  app:trackColor="#D3D3D3"
  app:trackThickness="10dp" />
```

[image]

References

- https://material.io/components/progress-indicators/android
- https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/progressindicator/CircularProgressIndicator
- https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android

Comment: This answer saved my day! Thanks a bunch!!