# How to Create a circular progressbar in Android which rotates on it?

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar, progress-indicator

I am trying to create a rounded progressbar. This is what I want to achieve

There is a grey color background ring. On top of it, a blue color progressbar appears which moves in a circular path from 0 to 360 in 60 or whatever amount of seconds.

[image]

Here is my example code.

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progressBarBG"
            android:progress="50"
            />
```

To do this, in the drawable "progressBarBG", I am creating a layerlist and inside that layer list I am giving two items as shown.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:innerRadius="64dp"
            android:thickness="8dp"
            android:useLevel="false">

        <solid android:color="@color/grey" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape
                android:shape="ring"
                android:innerRadius="64dp"
                android:thickness="8dp"
                android:useLevel="false">

            <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

Now, the first grey ring is generated fine. The blue ring however starts from the left of the drawable and goes to the right just like how a linear progressbar works. This is how it shows at 50% progress with the red color arrow showing direction.

[image]

I want to move the blue progressbar in circular path as expected.

Comment: I looked before posting this question. I found some answers but they did not work for what I am trying to achieve. Maybe someone downvoted me thinking this is a duplicate post.

Comment: I think you will need a customized solution. A ProgressBar, when not in indeterminate mode, uses a clip drawable to clip the progress layer of the drawable. But clip drawables only work horizontally or vertically, not as an angular wedge. I think you will have to create a subclass of Drawable to draw an arc that spans `getLevel()*360` degrees. And then since you can't use a custom view in an xml drawable, you will have to subclass ProgressBar so it will directly use your custom Drawable .

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776587/android-circular-determinate-progressbar

Comment: maybe this can point you in the right direction https://github.com/grmaciel/two-level-circular-progress-bar

Comment: you can use this library https://github.com/emre1512/CircleProgressBar

Comment: can anyone suggest how to do this type of progress bar https://drive.google.com/file/d/1coNXNUUAmo1tbgjnz6YitcXWaGibZTKg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://github.com/Adilhusen/circle-progress-ad-android

Comment: This is totally unrelated but google search for filled android circular progress bar is showing me this question again and again so i am posting a link to show filled circular progress bar in android below. [Filled Circular android progressbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67154062/show-circular-progress-bar-on-android-filled-circle/67154063#67154063) Feel free to down vote but please do not delete this answer as it might help people in future looking for a different type of progressbar and coming to the same answer again and again.

Answer (score 388):

Here are my two solutions.

**Short answer:**

Instead of creating a `layer-list`, I separated it into two files. One for `ProgressBar` and one for its background.

This is the `ProgressDrawable` file (@drawable folder): **circular_progress_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="270"
    android:toDegrees="270">
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="1dp"
        android:useLevel="true"><!-- this line fixes the issue for lollipop api 21 -->

        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:endColor="#007DD6"
            android:startColor="#007DD6"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

And this is for its `background`(@drawable folder): **circle_shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
    android:thickness="1dp"
    android:useLevel="false">

    <solid android:color="#CCC" />

</shape>
```

And at the end, inside the layout that you're working:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="65" />
```

Here's the result:

[image: result 1]

**Long Answer:**

Use a custom view which inherits the `android.view.View`

[image: result 2]

Here is the full project [on github](https://github.com/MRezaNasirloo/CircularProgressBar)

Comment: @Pedram How should I set percentage to the progress bar? Like for example, currently it'd 50%. How should I set the 50% to the progress bar?

Comment: @20 Cents, Read the documentation, you should get a reference to your progressbar and the call its `setProgress` method then pass the value. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=HbEuVOCSK8fiavW3gdAH&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&usg=AFQjCNHuxEkeDHP4UeDgdafyiPKGcoNtsQ&sig2=wUYbO83HxALfzoO26oyYJA

Comment: I went nuts trying to find the correct values, red dozens of stackoverflow topics, only to find the solution here.. `android:fromDegrees="270" android:toDegrees="270"` solved it!! Many thanks!

Comment: @Skynet Yes, and I haven't tried to fix it because I prefer to create a fully customized one with extending the View Class http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: In git repository it is showing error in  colorPickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "color_picker"); MainActivity.java class. Can you help me why this is showing error here?

Comment: is it usable in a widget?

Comment: @Pedram, your old solution is definitely better! check my answer down the page and fix your solution (I couldn't post it as a comment -- too long!)

Comment: @MimArmand Hey thanks, Actually it start working again in lollipop 5.1 update, And that line fixes the issue for api 21.

Comment: @Pedran Thank you so much for your answer, it seems that the useLevel set to true helped me as well on 5.0.2. Do you know the reason for using that attribute? I've never used it before...

Comment: Thank you. It is very laconic solution! `ObjectAnimator` is brilliant thing

Comment: Need to add android:indeterminate="true"  and android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar" as well to get the animation effect

Comment: For counter-clockwise direction, use negative sweepAngle.

Comment: @M.RezaNasirloo how can I add percentage in the middle of the circle?

Comment: hello if we want to add drawable then how can we do that ? coz shap does not allow drawable.

Comment: @M.RezaNasirloo I have implemented any thing you said , but it is not giving me animation as it has to. is there any thing I am missing for animation?

Comment: @KamranAli The short answer does not have animation, click on the GitHub link for a solution with animation

Comment: Actually it doesn't have to do anything with animation, it solved my problem I've set progress in points value so it solved my problem.

Comment: How to make the progress shape cornered with radius?

Answer (score 37):

With the Material Components Library you can use the **`CircularProgressIndicator`**:

Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
    app:indicatorColor="@color/...."
    app:trackColor="@color/...."
    app:indicatorSize="64dp"/>
```

You can use these attributes:

- `indicatorSize`:  defines the radius of the circular progress indicator
- `trackColor`: the color used for the progress track. If not defined, it will be set to the `indicatorColor` and apply the `android:disabledAlpha` from the theme.
- `indicatorColor`: the single color used for the indicator in determinate/indeterminate mode. By default it uses theme primary color

[image]

Use `progressIndicator.setProgressCompat((int) value, true);` to update the value in the indicator.

**Note:** it requires at least the version `1.3.0-alpha04`.

Comment: What is the required library dependency?

Comment: @bikram The [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) provided by google.

Comment: I added implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0' to build.gradle but still ProgressIndicator doesn't appear.

Comment: @bikram As described in the answer: it requires at least the version `1.3.0-alpha01`.

Answer (score 32):

I have done with easy way:

Please check screen shot for the same.

[image]

**CustomProgressBarActivity.java**:

```
public class CustomProgressBarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView txtProgress;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private int pStatus = 0;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_progressbar);

        txtProgress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtProgress);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (pStatus <= 100) {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setProgress(pStatus);
                            txtProgress.setText(pStatus + " %");
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    pStatus++;
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }
}
```

**activity_custom_progressbar.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.skholingua.android.custom_progressbar_circular.MainActivity" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progressbar_drawable"
            android:secondaryProgress="0" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtProgress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

**custom_progressbar_drawable.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="-90"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="270" >

    <shape
        android:shape="ring"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <gradient
            android:centerY="0.5"
            android:endColor="#FA5858"
            android:startColor="#0099CC"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>

</rotate>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Hiren, I am trying to display only two colors in the view. Red and green. But I see some mixture of red and green in the circle as well. How can i remove that ?

Answer (score 29):

I have written detailed example on [circular progress bar in android](https://demonuts.com/circular-progress-bar/) here on my blog [demonuts.com](http://demonuts.com). You can also fond full source code and explanation there.

Here's how I made circular progressbar with percentage inside circle in pure code without any library.

[image]

first create a drawable file called `circular.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="6"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="20.0"
            android:useLevel="true">


            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#999999"
                android:endColor="#999999"
                android:startColor="#999999"
                android:type="sweep" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="270"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="270">

            <shape
                android:innerRadiusRatio="6"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thicknessRatio="20.0"
                android:useLevel="true">


                <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="0"
                    android:pivotX="50%"
                    android:pivotY="50%"
                    android:toDegrees="360" />

                <gradient
                    android:centerColor="#00FF00"
                    android:endColor="#00FF00"
                    android:startColor="#00FF00"
                    android:type="sweep" />

            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now in your `activity_main.xml`  add following:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dialog"
    tools:context="com.example.parsaniahardik.progressanimation.MainActivity">

    <ProgressBar

        android:id="@+id/circularProgressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular"
        android:secondaryProgress="100"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@drawable/whitecircle"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="25%"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In `activity_main.xml` I have used one circular image with white background to show white background around percentage. Here is the image:

[image]

You can change color of this image to set custom color around percentage text.

Now finally add following code to `MainActivity.java` :

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int pStatus = 0;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Resources res = getResources();
        Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.circular);
        final ProgressBar mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.circularProgressbar);
        mProgress.setProgress(0);   // Main Progress
        mProgress.setSecondaryProgress(100); // Secondary Progress
        mProgress.setMax(100); // Maximum Progress
        mProgress.setProgressDrawable(drawable);

      /*  ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mProgress, "progress", 0, 100);
        animation.setDuration(50000);
        animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        animation.start();*/

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while (pStatus < 100) {
                    pStatus += 1;

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            mProgress.setProgress(pStatus);
                            tv.setText(pStatus + "%");

                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        // Sleep for 200 milliseconds.
                        // Just to display the progress slowly
                        Thread.sleep(8); //thread will take approx 1.5 seconds to finish
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

If you want to make horizontal progressbar, follow this link, it has many valuable examples with source code:
http://www.skholingua.com/android-basic/user-interface/form-widgets/progressbar

Comment: Nice and well-looked bar! But I don't understand why you're using a png image for background, not a compound drawable, so here is it: `<shape
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="oval"
 >
 
  <corners android:radius="1dp" />
 
  <solid
   android:color="@android:color/white"
   />
 
  <size
   android:width="250dp"
   android:height="250dp"
   />
 
</shape>`

Answer (score 22):

I realized a **Open Source library on GitHub** [**CircularProgressBar**](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularProgressBar) that does exactly what you want the simplest way possible:

[image: Gif demo CircularProgressBar]

### USAGE

To make a circular ProgressBar add **CircularProgressBar** in your layout XML and add **CircularProgressBar library** in your projector or you can also grab it via Gradle:

```
compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularprogressbar:1.0.0'
```

### XML

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularprogressbar.CircularProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:background_progressbar_color="#FFCDD2"
    app:background_progressbar_width="5dp"
    app:progressbar_color="#F44336"
    app:progressbar_width="10dp" />
```

You must use the following properties in your XML to change your CircularProgressBar.

**Properties:**

- `app:progress`                      (integer)   >> default 0
- `app:progressbar_color`             (color)     >> default BLACK
- `app:background_progressbar_color`  (color)     >> default GRAY
- `app:progressbar_width`             (dimension) >> default 7dp
- `app:background_progressbar_width`  (dimension) >> default 3dp

### JAVA

```
CircularProgressBar circularProgressBar = (CircularProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.yourCircularProgressbar);
circularProgressBar.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.progressBarColor));
circularProgressBar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.backgroundProgressBarColor));
circularProgressBar.setProgressBarWidth(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.progressBarWidth));
circularProgressBar.setBackgroundProgressBarWidth(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.backgroundProgressBarWidth));
int animationDuration = 2500; // 2500ms = 2,5s
circularProgressBar.setProgressWithAnimation(65, animationDuration); // Default duration = 1500ms
```

Fork or Download this library here >> [**https://github.com/lopspower/CircularProgressBar**](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularProgressBar)

Comment: I Try this it's really awesome but now found any animation change listener.    Are you know any way ?

Comment: @lopez.mikhael Hey do you have any ideas how to add an image in between the circular?

Comment: @DeniseTan you can simply used a FrameLayout or a RelativeLayout to do that.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a simple customview for display circle progress. You can modify and optimize more to suitable for your project.

```
class CircleProgressBar @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    private val backgroundWidth = 10f
    private val progressWidth = 20f

    private val backgroundPaint = Paint().apply {
        color = Color.LTGRAY
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeWidth = backgroundWidth
        isAntiAlias = true
    }

    private val progressPaint = Paint().apply {
        color = Color.RED
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeWidth = progressWidth
        isAntiAlias = true
    }

    var progress: Float = 0f
        set(value) {
            field = value
            invalidate()
        }

    private val oval = RectF()
    private var centerX: Float = 0f
    private var centerY: Float = 0f
    private var radius: Float = 0f

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        centerX = w.toFloat() / 2
        centerY = h.toFloat() / 2
        radius = w.toFloat() / 2 - progressWidth
        oval.set(centerX - radius,
                centerY - radius,
                centerX + radius,
                centerY + radius)
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas?.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, backgroundPaint)
        canvas?.drawArc(oval, 270f, 360f * progress, false, progressPaint)
    }
}
```

**Example using**

xml

```
<com.example.androidcircleprogressbar.CircleProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/circle_progress"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp" />
```

kotlin

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val TOTAL_TIME = 10 * 1000L

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...

        timeOutRemoveTimer.start()
    }

    private var timeOutRemoveTimer = object : CountDownTimer(TOTAL_TIME, 10) {
        override fun onFinish() {
            circle_progress.progress = 1f
        }

        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            circle_progress.progress = (TOTAL_TIME - millisUntilFinished).toFloat() / TOTAL_TIME
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is working fine and one thing how i can complete the progress manaully

Comment: How i can disable the background layout because it is behaving like transparent

Answer (score 5):

I'm new so I can't comment but thought to share the lazy fix. I use Pedram's original approach as well, and just ran into the same Lollipop issue. But [alanv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26554842/4240449) over in another post had a one line fix.  Its some kind of bug or oversight in API21.  Literally just add `android:useLevel="true"` to your circle progress xml.  Pedram's new approach is still the proper fix, but I just thought I share the lazy fix as well.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_circular_id"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:progress="30"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:max="100">
    </ProgressBar>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_progress_status_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="50%"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="35dp">
    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="click me"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progress_circular_id"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Create a Drawable File with name **circle_shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
    android:thickness="25dp"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <solid android:color="#CCC" />

</shape>
```

Create a file with **circular_progress_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="270"
    android:toDegrees="270">
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="25dp"
        android:useLevel="true"><!-- this line fixes the issue for lollipop api 21 -->

        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:endColor="#007DD6"
            android:startColor="#007DD6"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

**In java File For example purpose used fragmet.**

```
public class FragmentRegistration extends BaseFragmentHelper {
    View registrationFragmentView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    Button button;
    int count=0;
    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(@NonNull Fragment childFragment) {
        super.onAttachFragment(childFragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        registrationFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_device_registration, container, false);
        progressBar=(ProgressBar)registrationFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.progress_circular_id);
        button=(Button) registrationFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.check);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count=count+10;
                progressBar.setProgress(count);
            }
        });
        return registrationFragmentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
}
```

Comment: You made it complicated, keep it simple,

Comment: @HarikrushnaPatel
can u please point out the complication and paste the simple code as u mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

try this method to create a bitmap and set it to image view.

```
private void circularImageBar(ImageView iv2, int i) {


    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 300,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b); 
    Paint paint = new Paint();

        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#c4c4c4"));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawCircle(150, 150, 140, paint);

        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFDB4C"));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);   
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        final RectF oval = new RectF();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        oval.set(10,10,290,290);

        canvas.drawArc(oval, 270, ((i*360)/100), false, paint);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);    
        paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#8E8E93")); 
        paint.setTextSize(140);

        canvas.drawText(""+i, 150, 150+(paint.getTextSize()/3), paint); 

        iv2.setImageBitmap(b);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

@Pedram, your old solution works actually fine in lollipop too (and better than new one since it's usable everywhere, including in remote views) just change your `circular_progress_bar.xml` code to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="270"
    android:toDegrees="270">
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="1dp"
        android:useLevel="true"> <!-- Just add this line -->
        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:endColor="#007DD6"
            android:startColor="#007DD6"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

Comment: Excellent remark on android:useLevel="true"!!! You helped me to solve important issue on Android 5! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/passsy/android-HoloCircularProgressBar is one example of a library that does this. As Tenfour04 stated, it will have to be *somewhat* custom, in that this is not supported directly out of the box. If this library doesn't behave as you wish, you can fork it and modify the details to make it work to your liking. If you implement something that others can then reuse, you could even submit a pull request to get that merged back in!

Comment: I saw this library too but did not want to use another 3rd party library for this small task only. However, I am going to try both the methods mentioned by you and Tenfour04 to see which one works for me and reply back here.

Comment: @SauravSrivastava: I am also looking for a similar animation in my app.Have you found the solution? If yes,please share the solution.

Comment: @Travis Please see this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44801280/drawing-a-circle-and-show-data-as-per-the-data-set

Answer (score 2):

```
package com.example.ankitrajpoot.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ProgressBar spinner;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinner=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

> xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"

    android:layout_width="48dp"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
    android:indeterminate="true" />
</RelativeLayout>





<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="1080">
    <shape
        android:shape="ring"
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:thicknessRatio="8"
        android:useLevel="false">

        <size
            android:width="56dip"
            android:height="56dip" />

        <gradient
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false"
            android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:endColor="#1e9dff"
            android:angle="0"
            />

    </shape>
</rotate>
```

Comment: You sould cosider adding a description of the proposed solution.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
android:useLevel="false"
```

to

```
android:useLevel="true"
```

for second sahpe with `id="@android:id/progress`

hope it works

Answer (score 2):

Good news is that now [material design library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases) supports *determinate* circular progress bars too:

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

For more info about this refer [here](https://material.io/components/progress-indicators/android#using-progress-indicators).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set progress in an anti-clock direction then use below image for set `fromDegree` and `toDegree`'s values in progressDrawble xml.

[image]

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="270"
    android:toDegrees="-90">
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="2"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="1dp"> 
        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:endColor="#007DD6"
            android:startColor="#007DD6"
            android:type="sweep" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

This code will let your progress anti-clockwise and from the top.
Change the degrees as per the above image from where you want to rotate your progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library https://github.com/xYinKio/ArcCircleProgressBar

This is one of the most flexible circular progress bars

[This picture is showing the lib powers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcv3A.png)