# ProgressBar Circle shows no progress on android L (API 21)

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a circular ProgressBar to count down time. It workes perfectly on kitkat and before, but on android L it always shows a full circle no matter what progress I set.

[Image](http://youspeakschwaebisch.de/progressbar.jpg)

**layout.xml**

```
<ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:indeterminate="false"
                android:max="200"
                android:progress="100"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progresscircle" />
```

**progresscircle.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="3.4"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="6.0" >
            <solid 
                android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
        <item>
            <rotate
                android:drawable="@drawable/progress_particle"
                android:fromDegrees="0"
                android:pivotX="50%"
                android:pivotY="50%"
                android:toDegrees="360" />
        </item>

    </layer-list>
```

Comment: Your start and end colors are identical when expanded to ARGB. Have you tried android:startColor="#00ffffff"?

Comment: You're right, this used to be two different colors. Now it should be just white (see updated question). Problem is still the same.

Comment: What is the expected behavior? Can you include a screenshot? From the code, it looks like a solid ring that rotates around its center -- which would look the same at every point in the animation.

Comment: I linked a screenshot above, because i can't include it directly with reputation below 10. Here's the link: http://youspeakschwaebisch.de/progressbar.jpg

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The default value for android:useLevel under the  tag incorrectly changed to false in the L Preview build. You can work around this by explicitly setting it to true.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape
            ...
            android:useLevel="true">
            <solid
                ...
```

Comment: This has been fixed in the master branch for a future release.

Comment: says 'android:useLevelForShape' is an unknown attribute but 'android:useLevel' worked!

Comment: Oops! Sorry, yes the correct attribute name is useLevel. The field that it gets loaded into is mUseLevelForShape. ;)

Comment: I'm afraid the master, official update, pushed over the air also has this problem

Comment: Yep, the fix is still pending release.

Comment: Is there an issue report open for this?

Comment: No, but if you want to file one on the AOSP issue tracker then I will keep it updated.

Comment: can you please let me know what does "uselevel" attribute signify .Could not make sense from android doc