# How to pass AttributeSet as a parameter

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement updated solution by Pedram from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333866/create-a-circular-progressbar-in-android-which-rotates-on-circular-path) answer, but I don't know to create a new instance of `CircleProgressBar`. It requires AttributeSet to be passed as a parameter, but how to get it?

```
CircleProgressBar circleProgressBar = new CircleProgressBar(MainActivity.this, ?);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AttributeSet` constructor is used when a view is inflated through a layout defined in XML. If you're constructing one in code, you should use the single argument constructor (e.g. `new CircleProgressBar(MainActivity.this)`). If the single-argument constructor is not defined, you just need to add it. You'll just need to add some getters/setters for the properties if you want to be able to construct it entirely from within Java code.

Alternately, just define a layout XML (example name view_progress_circle.xml) with a single item:

```
<com.your.packagename.CircleProgressBar
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    // etc. add other attributes here
    />
```

Then in code, create it with:

```
CircleProgressBar bar = (CircleProgressBar) LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this)
        .inflate(R.layout.view_progress_circle, parent, false):
```

where `parent` is the `ViewGroup` you're going to attach the view to.