# Android. Material design button programmatically

Tags: android, material-design, android-button

I want to show material design button like this:

[image]

I am using [MaterialDesignLibrary](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary). In XML, I can show it in this way:

```
<com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#1E88E5"
                android:text="Button" />
```

How to show this button **programmatically**?

Comment: Tell me why you are minusing me?

Answer (score 0):

Update :

First extend the class in your project :

```
public class MyButtonRectangle extends ButtonRectangle {

    public MyButtonRectangle(Context context) {
        super(context, null); //Pass null for AttributeSet Params
    }
}
```

Than create new MyButtonRectangle as any other view in Android:

```
MyButtonRectangle btn = new MyButtonRectangle(this);
btn.setId(R.id.someId); // you need to add dummy id in ids.xml in values folder.
btn.setText("Button");
btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorName));

LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); // Replace LinearLayout with your base layout like RelativeLayout,  FrameLayout,  etc.

btn.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I also tought like this. But it has this constructor: ButtonRectangle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs). Can you help with this: I cannot figure out what I should send for AttributeSet attrs?

Comment: Extend the class in your android app and add a new constructor to read only context. Check my edited answer in few mins

Comment: I have tried use custom class as you suggested. But it calls parent(ButtonRectangle)'s contructor. The contructor needs AttributeSet attrs.

Comment: As I stated replace ButtonRectangle btn = new ButtonRectangle(this);
to MyButtonRectangle btn = new MyButtonRectangle(this);

Comment: I understood that I should create custom class instance. But I have error inside MyRectangleButton

Comment: Ok. Give me 5 mins. I am booting my PC. Will test and update my Answer in few mins.

Comment: Am sorry there seems no easy way to do this. You will have to import the whole library as a module and manually modify the ButtonRectangle Java file to support single parameter constructor. Or follow this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379150/how-to-pass-attributeset-as-a-parameter

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention!)

Comment: Check my edited comment. Please upvote and accept my answer to show support.

Comment: Unfortunately, this way is also not working. Anyways, thank you for your help:) I will try to come up with some solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102251/discussion-between-arnab-jain-and-joe-richard).

Comment: Hello, Check my updated answer. It should do the job.