# Custom Progress bar with image

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I know this question has been asked before, but I've spent a lot of time trying to interpret answers with no success.

I'm trying to get an **animated circular progress bar with image.**
I refer this [link](https://github.com/ylyc/circular_progress_bar) for basic understanding but how can i create customized progress bar with image..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893209/how-to-customize-a-progress-bar-in-android

Comment: what type of progress bar you trying to get??

Comment: see this [link image](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Wlp3VRI4nnk/Vlfm65p1UhI/AAAAAAAABb8/LNfRuEdaRWU/w191-h212-no/progressBar.png) 
i want to develop like this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333866/how-to-create-a-circular-progressbar-in-android-which-rotates-on-it

Answer (score 0):

I made a custom class which extend by dialog. may be this will helpful for you

```
public class CProgressDialog extends Dialog {

private ImageView iv;

public CProgressDialog(Context context) {
    super(context, R.style.TransparentProgressDialog);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlmp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    wlmp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
    getWindow().setAttributes(wlmp);
    setTitle(null);
    setCancelable(false);
    setOnCancelListener(null);
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    iv = new ImageView(context);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.spiner_green);
    layout.addView(iv, params);
    addContentView(layout, params); 
}

@Override
public void show() {
    super.show();
    RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            .5f);
    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    anim.setDuration(2000);
    iv.setAnimation(anim);
    iv.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Comment: kindly describe me that how to use this class in progressbar.. please check this [link](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Wlp3VRI4nnk/Vlfm65p1UhI/AAAAAAAABb8/LNfRuEdaRWU/w191-h212-no/progressBar.png) i want to do like this image.

Comment: well what i suggested you is not that what you are looking for... use third party library or take idea from there... https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel  and  https://bitbucket.org/mythings/circleprogressbutton