# Android circular progress bar slows down at it progresses

Tags: java, android, xml, progress-bar

I've implemented a circular progress bar that fills up in 10 seconds time. However, I think the bar fills up quicker in the beginning, and, as a result, it slows down (the animation of it filling) as the time goes on. In addition, at the end, it stops for moment and then finally finishes. The code I used I got from the first answer here:
[How to Create a circular progressbar in Android which rotates on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333866/how-to-create-a-circular-progressbar-in-android-which-rotates-on-it)

And then my code which starts the progress bar is:

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt (progressBar, "progress", 0, 100);
animation.setDuration (10000);
animation.setInterpolator (new DecelerateInterpolator());
animation.start();
```

How can I make the animation smoother?

Comment: May be this could help

[link](https://github.com/Pedramrn/CircularProgressBar)

Comment: It seems like that would be a lot more code to achieve what I already have. I guess it'd be better if it were smoother, but I'd like to know why mine is having this problem.

Comment: its because of DecelerateInterpolator. Use LinearInterpolator instead.

Comment: You are using a `DecelerateInterpolator` which is meant to slow down any animation towards the end. What do you mean by smoother? I think [this tutorial](http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=1078) on interpolators could help you.

Comment: oh. my. god...you guys are geniuses. Lol thanks!!

Comment: While I have your attention, my progress bar goes up only as a button is being held. Do you know how I can stop the progress and reset it to 0 if the button is released before the 10 second time limit is reached?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are using `DecelerateInterpolator`. An interpolator defines the rate of change of an animation. This allows the basic animation effects to be accelerated, decelerated, repeated, etc.

You can read more about interpolator [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html).

You can either use [LinearInterpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/LinearInterpolator.html) or [AccelerateInterpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AccelerateInterpolator.html) whichever serves your purpose.