# How to create Diamond Progress Bar Android

Tags: android, android-view, android-progressbar

My Client wants a diamond shaped progress that looks like this:

[image]

My first attempt was to use a library, but I can't find one that exists

My next attempt was to learn how to use the `ProgressBar` view that comes with android, and set my own drawable using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333866/how-to-create-a-circular-progressbar-in-android-which-rotates-on-it) answer (the closest thing to an answer on stack overflow), but the answer only works on `ring` shapes, not rectangles.

**What is the best way to create a diamond-shaped progress view? (By any means: custom view, progressDrawable) and how do I do that?**

Comment: If you're looking for a library, you're off topic.  If you're looking to do it yourself, break it down to one specific question at a time.

Comment: Updated question... hope I made it more clear

Comment: I guess you can also have a look on this library: https://github.com/mrwonderman/android-square-progressbar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some more tests, I came up with a hacky answer. It's just 4 progress bars aligned to the edge of a Relative layout, and a `CardView` on top of them. Rotate the whole thing, and wrap it in a class and bam, you got yourself a diamond progress bar. (Use math to calculate the progress of each bar)

[image]

It can be a little weird on the corners (where the progress bars overlap) but overall it works well enough

Usage:

```
ViewGroup background;
int count = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Something to add the progress bar to
    background = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.relative);

    //initializing the progress bar
    final DiamondProgress diamondProgress = new DiamondProgress(this);
    diamondProgress.setMax(1000);

    //adding the progress bar
    background.addView(diamondProgress.getView());

    /* Sample Code for animating the progress bar*/
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    diamondProgress.setProgress(count++);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 25);


}
```

Code:

**XML: layout/diamond_view**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:rotation="45"
    android:padding="43dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:rotation="90"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:rotation="180">
                <ProgressBar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:id="@+id/dp_progress4"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_drawable"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:rotation="180">
            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:progress="50"
                android:id="@+id/dp_progress3"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_drawable"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:rotation="90"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:progress="100"
                android:id="@+id/dp_progress2"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_drawable"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:progress="100"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_drawable"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:id="@+id/dp_progress1"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/dp_card"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:rotation="-45"
                android:id="@+id/dp_addView"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Sample Inside Content"
                    android:id="@+id/dp_text"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="24sp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**XML: drawable/progress_drawable**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--  background -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#f2f2f2" />
        </shape>

    </item>


    <!-- for the actual progress bar -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip android:gravity="left">
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
                <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**Java Class**

```js
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

/**
 * Created by Pythogen on 9/27/2017.
 */

public class DiamondProgress {

    Context context;
    View view;
    RelativeLayout addView;
    int progress = 0;
    int max = 100;
    ProgressBar p1;
    ProgressBar p2;
    ProgressBar p3;
    ProgressBar p4;


    public DiamondProgress(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.diamond_view, null);
        addView = ((RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.dp_addView));
        p1 = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.dp_progress1);
        p2 = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.dp_progress2);
        p3 = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.dp_progress3);
        p4 = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.dp_progress4);

    }

    public View getView() {
        return view;
    }

    public RelativeLayout getHostOfInsideContent() {
        return addView;
    }

    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
        updateProgressBar();
    }

    public void setMax(int max) {
        this.max = max;
        p1.setMax(max);
        p2.setMax(max);
        p3.setMax(max);
        p4.setMax(max);
    }

    public void updateProgressBar() {
        double prog = ((double)progress)/max;
        if (prog<.25) {
            p1.setProgress(this.progress*4);
            p2.setProgress(0);
            p3.setProgress(0);
            p4.setProgress(0);
        } else {
            p1.setProgress(max);
            if (prog<.5) {
                p2.setProgress((this.progress*4)-max);
                p3.setProgress(0);
                p4.setProgress(0);
            } else {
                p2.setProgress(max);
                if (prog<.75) {
                    p3.setProgress((this.progress*4)-max*2);
                    p4.setProgress(0);
                } else {
                    p3.setProgress(max);
                    p4.setProgress((this.progress*4)-max*3);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Oh, and if you plan on using this, be sure to add the CardView dependancy to your build.grade `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'`

Comment: what i should call for this?