# Determinate circular progress bar in android

Tags: java, android

I want to make a determinate progress bar but current code gives always indeterminated

My XML

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.07"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="20"
        />
```

My Code

```
holder.pb=rowView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar3);
holder.pb.setIndeterminate(false);
//holder.pb.setIndeterminateDrawable(null);
holder.pb.setProgress(50);
holder.pb.setMax(100);
holder.pb.requestLayout();
```

Comment: Please explain your question properly. What are you expecting from your question?

Comment: someone edited the question wrong,,,, sorry,,, I want to make a determinate progress bar but current code gives always indeterminated

Comment: so how can do for circular?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333866/how-to-create-a-circular-progressbar-in-android-which-rotates-on-it
this might help you

Comment: @sarath19 yes it works ) how can I vote

Comment: i am glad it helped , u cannot upvote unless you have a reputation of 15 and above.

Answer (score 1):

This is my implementation of a circular progress view. (Does support bind its value to a TextView)

Works on Android 16+ (or lower didnt tested)

Set a Total and a Progress.

Important THIS VIEW doesnt measure itself, so you need to give some square properties like width=100dp height=100dp

```
package app.view;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by MarcosVasconcelos on 28/07/2017.
 */
public class CircularProgressView extends View {
    private final float strokeWidth;
    private Paint totalPaint, progressPaint;
    private float progress = 360;
    private float total = 360;
    public TextView textView;

    public CircularProgressView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        strokeWidth = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 8, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        totalPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        totalPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        totalPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CCCCCC"));
        totalPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);

        progressPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        progressPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        progressPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        progressPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.save();

        drawProgress(canvas, (int) 360f, totalPaint);
        if(total != 0 && progress != 0)
            drawProgress(canvas, total == progress ? 360 : (int) ((360f / total) * progress), progressPaint);

        canvas.restore();
    }

    private void drawProgress(Canvas canvas, int total, Paint paint) {
        canvas.drawArc(new RectF(strokeWidth, strokeWidth, getWidth() - strokeWidth, getHeight() - strokeWidth), -90, total, false, paint);
    }

    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setProgressColor(int rgb) {
        progressPaint.setColor(rgb);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
        if(textView != null)
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(total));
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setTotalTextView(TextView view) {
        this.textView = view;
        textView.setText(String.valueOf((int)total));
    }
}
```

Comment: "package br.gov" - are you sure you are allowed to share that

Comment: Lol, the solution has no business logic, i just removed the package declaration

Comment: Lol, why would you edit it out if you are so sure you are allowed to share it

Comment: Cause its not relevant for the question ;)