# Increment RingProgressBar by 1 in Android

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

How to increment the `RingProgressBar` by 1 on `Button` click in android.

I create a button and ring progress bar.
How can implement like, whenever `Button` clicked Progress is increment by 1

Comment: see this link, it may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333866/how-to-create-a-circular-progressbar-in-android-which-rotates-on-it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Create a circular progressbar in Android which rotates on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333866/how-to-create-a-circular-progressbar-in-android-which-rotates-on-it)

Comment: I CREATE ONE BUTTON AND ONE PROGRESS BAR.NOW QUESTION IS THAT  WHEN I CLICK THAT BUTTON THE PROGRESS BAR SHOULD INCREMENT BY 1 AND AGAIN IF I CLICK THAT SAME BUTTON THEN PROGRESS BAR SHOULD AGAIN INCREMENT BY 2. PLEASE NEED A HELP FOR THE JAVA CODE IN ANDROID STUDIO.