# Use a Circular Progress to Create a car Speedometer alike

Tags: java, android, android-studio, progress-bar, android-location

[image]I have a circular progress bar, what i want to do is to use it to measure speed, something like a car speedometer, but i don't know how to do this[SOMETHING LIKE THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dps7u.png). Or if it is possible using a circular progress bar. So what i was doing was store the speed in a variable and the use progressbar.setProgress to get the speed. But it's not working because i think is not right, So Any advice or suggestion is welcome.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 ProgressBar mprogressBar;

 @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mprogressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.circular_progress_bar);
    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mprogressBar, "progress", (int)speeeeed, 25);
    Log.e("valor de speed", Double.toString(speeeeed));
    mprogressBar.setProgress((int) speeeeed);
    anim.setDuration(15000);
    anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    anim.start();
}



LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                float Real =(location.getSpeed()*3600/1000);
                String convertedSpeed = String.format("%.2f",Real);
                TVKm.setText(convertedSpeed);
    }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                                    Bundle extras) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    };
```

circularprogressbar.xml

```
<shape
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
  android:shape="ring"
  android:thickness="10dp"
  android:useLevel="true">
<solid android:color="#e6c009" />
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/circular_progress_bar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:max="48"
            android:progress="1"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progressbar" />
```

Comment: do you have any image for what you actually want to do ?

Comment: YES @quicklearner LET ME UPDATE THE POST

Comment: Check this :- 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333866/how-to-create-a-circular-progressbar-in-android-which-rotates-on-it  2) http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/03/android-downloading-file-with-circular.html

Comment: Thanks @ChiragGohil, i'll check it out!