# Make a custom progress bar in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

I need to make a custom progress bar that looks like this: [image]

I'd love some advice for the best way to do this.
thanks!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333866/how-to-create-a-circular-progressbar-in-android-which-rotates-on-it

Comment: *the best way to do this* is probably by typing code.

Comment: what is it with everyone spreading hate? it's a fellow coder asking a question.. stop being so mean and try to help.. isn't it why this site exist?

Comment: @JozeRi a *fellow coder* needs to code to be a coder. There is no code in this question. And no, *this* is **not** why the site exists, this ain't no free coding service. More about this in ... you guesses it, the same (very) old page everyone seems to think is not for them: [the help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Enjoy the read, it's a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress

There are already many libraries providing these type of progressbar. Check above one.

```
   allprojects {
        repositories {
            ...
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
    }
```

app level gradle.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1'
}
```

In your layout

```
 <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/donut_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom:donut_progress="30"/>
```

See https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress for all available customizations.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int x = canvas.getWidth();
    int y = canvas.getHeight();

    float left      = x/2 ;
    float top       = y/2 ;
    float right     = x/2 ;
    float bottom    = y/2 ;

    mRectF.left     = left;
    mRectF.top      = top;
    mRectF.right    = right;
    mRectF.bottom   = bottom;

    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);



    mPaint.setShader(null);
    canvas.drawCircle(x/2,y/2, strokeWidth* 1.5f,mPaint);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);


    mPaint.setShader(createGradient());
    canvas.drawArc(mRectF,0,360,false, mPaint);


    Shader mGradient = createGradient();
    mMatrix.setRotate(-90f, x / 2 , y / 2 );
    mGradient.setLocalMatrix(mMatrix);
    mPaint.setShader(mGradient);
    canvas.drawArc(mRectF,ANGLE_START,currentAngle,false, mPaint);

}
```