# Custom dialog ProgressBar with spinner and percent text

Tags: android, progressdialog

[image]How can i design a custom dialog with progress spinner along with percentage?

I have tried below but only get spinner along with title:

```
progress=new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setTitle("Uploading...");
    progress.setMessage("");
    progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progress.setIndeterminate(false);
    progress.setProgressNumberFormat("");
    progress.setProgress(0);
    progress.show();

    final int totalProgressTime = 100;
    final Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int jumpTime = 0;

            while(jumpTime < totalProgressTime) {
                try {
                    sleep(200);
                    jumpTime += 5;
                    progress.setProgress(jumpTime);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
```

any help to create a progress as attached will be helpful.

Comment: how about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333866/how-to-create-a-circular-progressbar-in-android-which-rotates-on-it and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333866/how-to-create-a-circular-progressbar-in-android-which-rotates-on-it

Comment: @VadimEksler both are same links. And i have already tried them

Answer (score 1):

Dunno if you checked it or not, but there is a nice tutorial about this [here](https://demonuts.com/circular-progress-bar/).

I guess you just need to adapt the code used there in MainActivity in your custom dialog code.

Hope it helps! Cheers ;)

Answer (score 0):

***CircleProgressBarActivity.java:***

```
public class CircleProgressBarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView txtProgress;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private int pStatus = 0;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_progressbar);

        txtProgress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtProgress);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (pStatus <= 100) {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setProgress(pStatus);
                            txtProgress.setText(pStatus + " %");
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    pStatus++;
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }
}
```

---

1. activity_custom_progressbar.xml:

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.skholingua.android.custom_progressbar_circular.MainActivity" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progressbar_drawable"
            android:secondaryProgress="0" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtProgress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

***custom_progressbar_drawable.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="-90"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="270" >

    <shape
        android:shape="ring"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <gradient
            android:centerY="0.5"
            android:endColor="#FA5858"
            android:startColor="#0099CC"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>

</rotate>
```