# How to implement circular to check / tick animation in Android?

Tags: android, android-animation, lottie

I am trying to animate a custom view

I implemented a circular progress bar custom view, exactly similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37159992/980898)

```
 @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
   {
       super.onDraw(canvas);

       if (totalCount == 0 || progressCount == 0)
       {
           // No progress, set a different background color and draw a arc and set a icon at the center
           progressBackgroundPaint.setColor(outerNoProgressBackgroundColor);
           canvas.drawArc(viewRect, PROGRESS_START_DEGREE, PROGRESS_END_DEGREE, false, progressBackgroundPaint);
           drawInnerBackgroundWithState(canvas, ProgressState.NO_PROGRESS);
           drawCenterIconWithState(centerIconEmptyBitmap, canvas, ProgressState.NO_PROGRESS);
       }
       else
       {
           // Change the color first for a progress bar
           progressBackgroundPaint.setColor(outerProgressBackgroundColor);
           canvas.drawArc(viewRect, PROGRESS_START_DEGREE, PROGRESS_END_DEGREE, false, progressBackgroundPaint);

           // Then draw an arc on top of it marking progress
           canvas.drawArc(viewRect, PROGRESS_START_DEGREE, getAngle(), false, progressPaint);

           // set inner background color and tint center icon with state-appropriate color and draw it in the center
           // of the progress circle
           if (progressCount < totalCount)
           {
               canvas.drawOval(viewRect, innerBackgroundPaint);
               drawCenterIconWithState(centerIconProgressBitmap, canvas, ProgressState.IN_PROGRESS); // draw bit map function
           }
           else
           {
               canvas.drawOval(viewRect, completeBackgroundPaint);
               drawCenterIconWithState(centerIconProgressBitmap, canvas, ProgressState.COMPLETE); // draw bitmap function
           }
       }
   }
```

I call this `onDraw` using `ValueAnimator`

```
public void drawProgressAnimation(float progress)
   {
ValueAnimator animator;
       if (animator != null)
           animator.cancel();
       animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, progress);
       animator.setDuration(600);

       progressAnimator.addUpdateListener(animation ->
       {
           float progress1 = (float)animation.getAnimatedValue();
           setProgress(progress1, true);
       });
       progressAnimator.start();
   }
```

And invalidating in `setProgress` method which calls `onDraw`.

But, I need to achieve something [like this](https://lottiefiles.com/782-check-mark-success?page=26),

I tried using Animator set along with `ValueAnimator`, but it didn't work. I tried to call `onDraw` with sequentially by setting a variable inside the lambda but in vain.
I am not sure whether can do this using `AnimatedVectorDrawable`. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

I used this repo as reference and implemented what i want. Instead of using random counter to set the speed. I used value animation and used the progress value for every frame to set the arc rate. And used the counter to draw circles that would grow from Zero to radius.

```
if (isComplete) {
    canvas.drawArc(mRect, START_DEGREE, getSweepAngle(), false, progressPaint);

    // animate circle progress when arc reaches partial sweep angle
    if (getSweepAngle() >= partialSweepAngle)
    {
        innerBackground.setColor(innerCompleteColor);
        circleCounter += circleProgressRate;

        if (circleCounter <= radius)
            canvas.drawCircle(mRect.centerX(), mRect.centerY(), circleCounter,
                innerBackground);
        else
            canvas.drawCircle(mRect.centerX(), mRect.centerY(), radius, innerBackground);
    }
    if (circleCounter >= radius)
        // draw the icon
}
```