# I want to have a circular seek bar in my android studio app

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, seekbar

I want to have a circular seek bar in my android studio app using kotlin, something like that:

[image]

Then I want to add an image in it to be a music app with a picture of the music and that seek bar represents the progress of the music.

It will be better if I could change the theme, and thanks for your time.

Comment: There's nothing built in for that.  You'll either need to find a library or write your own custom view.

Comment: This answer might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333866/how-to-create-a-circular-progressbar-in-android-which-rotates-on-it