# Show Circular progress bar on android (filled circle)

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-circularview

**How to show a filled circular progress bar on android?**

The progress bar should be filled like a circle not like a ring and it should have customizable features like animation timings animation interpolators etc.

Answer (score 0):

This project helps display a simple filled circular progress bar on android 5 (lolipop) and above.
It is extremely customizable all the custom attributes are shown in the code sample below.

This is an open source project, feel free to look into code or clone it and modify it per your requirements.

[Follow the GitHub instructions to get started](https://github.com/JeetR/CircularProgressBar-android)

```
<com.jeet.circularprogressbar.CircularProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/customRoundProgressBar"
       android:layout_width="100dp"
       android:layout_height="100dp"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:maxProgressLimit="60"
       app:progress="50"
       app:maxAnimationDuration="2500"
       app:animationInterpolator="AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator"
       app:showProgressText="true"
       app:progressTextSize="16sp"
       app:progressTextColor="@color/black"
       app:progressBarColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
```

Max progress limit by default is 100 and min progress limit by default is 0, none of the parameters are required other than width and height.

You can play with different interpolators to animate the progress values, **default is acceleratedecelateinterpolator**

The maximum Animation Duration can also be changed.

All the properties shown in xml can be changed from code as well

For example:

`setProgress(progressValue)`
can be called from code to set the current progress of the progress bar.

**Result**
[image: Filled Circular progress bar]