# How to make a filled circular progress bar? (without using external libraries)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I want to make a circular filled progress bar in Android Studio.
My goal is to achieve something like this;

[image: Example image]

The first image would have the progress value of for example, 100, then every second a bit of the circle will disappear until its nothing left.

[I tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67154062/show-circular-progress-bar-on-android-filled-circle) but I couldn't get my repositories to work, therefore I'm looking for a more "non external" way to do it.

Comment: That library is open source. [Here is the source code to the `CircularProgressBar`](https://github.com/JeetR/CircularProgressBar-android/blob/master/app/customcircleprogressbar/src/main/java/com/jeet/circularprogressbar/CircularProgressBar.java). You can review how that is implemented, and if you wish to create your own, learn from it. If you do not understand something about that code, feel free to ask Stack Overflow questions about the specifics.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will take a look at that.

Answer (score 2):

With the **Material Components library** you can use the official **`CircularProgressIndicator`**.
Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:trackThickness="20dp"    
                />
```

[image]

If you are using **jetpack Compose** you can use `CircularProgressIndicator`:

```
CircularProgressIndicator(
    strokeWidth = 20.dp, 
    progress = animatedProgress.value)
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I will definitely try this aswell.