# ProgressBar with circle on start like a seekbar

Tags: android, progress-bar

How add circle on start progressbar?
I'm customize this progressBar but cann't to add circle on start progress

**Image:**
[image]

**LAYOUT_LIST**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="30"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="#FDC410"/>
            <size android:width="100dp"
                android:height="100dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="270"
            android:toDegrees="270">
            <shape
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thicknessRatio="30"
                android:useLevel="true">
                <gradient
                    android:endColor="#AA6F04"
                    android:startColor="#D69622"
                    android:type="sweep" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**STYLE**

```
<style name="CircularDeterminateProgressBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/pb_circle</item>
</style>
```

**PROGRESSBAR**

```
   <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb_one"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:progress="75"
        style="@style/CircularDeterminateProgressBar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Please do not suggest using the seekbar. Seekbar does not have the functionality that I need

Comment: [You can check here] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333866/how-to-create-a-circular-progressbar-in-android-which-rotates-on-it

Comment: @MercanBirer I watch everywere, but don't find answer on my question

Comment: `Seekbar does not have the functionality that I need` -  [SeekBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar) is an extension of ProgressBar   What  functionality you do not find in seekbar and it's present in progress bar?

Comment: @Nitish I meant custom seekBar like that https://github.com/stefanodp91/CircularSeekBar

This seekbar extends from View

Comment: I search circular seekbar with gradient or progressBar with circle on start

Comment: Doesn't the link which you just shared supports the gradient color in the progress `app:cs_color_list : Integer vector used for gradient generation`. It's mentioned in the document that it's supports

Comment: @Nitish This external library working incorrerct on my and many other desktop. Android Studio Render cann't instalize that seekbar.