# How to create determinate circular progress bar android

Tags: android

Does any body has any idea of how to create circular progress bar with determinate range (0-100)? If not any guidance on how can I write one on my own??

Most of the solutions available online says to use style progressBarStyleHorizontal and change the progress drawable with custom xml. Custom xml makes use of progress particle.png image. Could not find such file online.

Please help. I have wasted hours on searching it and failed.Thanks in dvance.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213381/how-to-create-circular-progressbar-in-android

Comment: bro, its third party. I have some more customization needed for that circular progress bar like placing button in the center of progress bar and change its image with progress and all. So I cant use third party which wont let me place button in center.

Comment: Please do your research before asking on SO. The answer below was from a quick 2 second Google search.

Comment: @Ron please learn to read before u put your comments blindly. I have clearly stated that I cant use third party frameworks in my comment. In case u cant read sorry may god help you :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Circular Determinate ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776587/android-circular-determinate-progressbar)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [Circle Progress](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress) library

CircularProgress:

```
 <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.CircleProgress
    android:id="@+id/circle_progress"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    custom:circle_progress="20"/>
```

CircleProgress:

```
 <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.CircleProgress
    android:id="@+id/circle_progress"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    custom:circle_progress="20"/>
```

ArcProgress:

```
<com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.ArcProgress
    android:id="@+id/arc_progress"
    android:background="#214193"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    custom:arc_progress="55"
    custom:arc_bottom_text="MEMORY"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are available customizable code. This is easily searchable from Google: [How to create circular ProgressBar in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213381/how-to-create-circular-progressbar-in-android).