# Non custom drawable determinate circular ProgressBar per material guidelines

Tags: android

I am trying to use native Android SDK to create the circular determinate progress bar seen here:

https://material.io/design/components/progress-indicators.html#linear-progress-indicators

[image]

I have been reading the docs here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

But I can't figure it out. It seems determinate is only able to be used with horizontal progress bar.

I found this stackoverlfow topic here - [Android Circular Determinate ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776587/android-circular-determinate-progressbar) - but it ussing a custom drawable. Because we can make an indetermiante circular spinner as easily as this:

```
 <ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/determinateBar"
      style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Normal"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:indeterminate="true"/>
```

I was hoping to just add `android:progress="1"` and `android:indeterminate="false"` to get the circular determinate spinner we see above but this is not working.

Comment: Try to refer this [so thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213381/how-to-create-circular-progressbar-in-android) :)

Comment: Thank you @RobertoManfreda!

Comment: You are welcome :D