# Xml cannot have multiple root tags android

Tags: android, xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="45">
    <shape
        android:shape="ring"
        android:innerRadiusRatio="4.0"
        android:useLevel="true"
        android:thickness="20dp">
        <solid android:color="@color/defaultGreen2"></solid>
    </shape>

</rotate>
<layer-list>
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <color android:color="@color/defaultGreen2"/>
</item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <color android:color="@color/white"/>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

this is my code any other way of achieving circular determinate progressbar and using custom colors

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776587/android-circular-determinate-progressbar

Answer (score 0):

This is general XML Rule. consider putting  element in .

Like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list "xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android>
<item>
<rotate>
    android:fromDegrees="45">
    <shape
        android:shape="ring"
        android:innerRadiusRatio="4.0"
        android:useLevel="true"
        android:thickness="20dp">
        <solid android:color="@color/defaultGreen2"></solid>
    </shape>

</rotate>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <color android:color="@color/defaultGreen2"/>
</item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <color android:color="@color/white"/>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```