# How do I stop circular progressBar spinning?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, progress-bar

I have a progressBar in my xml. It's spinning all the time.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="167dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
/>
```

[image]

Is there a way to stop spinning it? Make it as round circle (as if %100 loaded).
I tried to set the progress parameter but nothing changed.
Is it possible at all or should I make a custom progressBar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop and start a ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314272/how-to-stop-and-start-a-progressbar)

Answer (score 1):

This situation is due to the use of the default indeterminate style (`android:style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle`").
This style is used for progress bars that don't have a known duration for completion.

Try this

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
```

You can now set

```
val progressBar: ProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
progressBar.progress = 50
```

If you still want it as a circle, you need to create your custom progress bar.

Comment: Yes, I need a circle one. I will look for it.  Thank you for the answer!